How can I ensure that the text prints perfectly aligned with the lines on the paper?
I don't know how to use Word so I need a detailed step-by-step guide on how to make the text perfectly aligned both in the header and in the lines below it.
Measurements

Header approximately 1.5 cm
First line below the header 0.5 cm
Remaining lines 0.7 cm
Paper dimensions
Height 12.4 cm
Width 20.2 cm
Epson l3250 printer



Word is not the right program to create such task. Think about some DTP software like Adobe InDesign

If you print the lines as well as the text onto plain paper then everything will be aligned. (There are several much lower cost options than InDesign, if budget is a constraint.)

@AndrewMorton, great comment -- but that could be expanded to an answer, helpful to others with that issue, by explaining how to make the lines. (Of course, that only works if one has the option of using blank paper.)


Where does the data come from? 2) Have you considered using Excel and setting the line height of the rows? Microsoft: Change the column width and row height.


This is extremely difficult to do, because it relies on the alignment of the printer. I hope the paper was flat when it went in, and was creased after it was printed. If it's not perfectly manufacturer-flat when it goes into the printer this will never work. The smeared "TEST" top right suggests that the printer alignment is not very good.
You need to get precise measurements for line spacing. Measure a large group of lines to the nearest mm and divide by the number of lines measured (minus one).
Make sure you turn the "rulers" on in Word. Get your page set up and compare the positions reported by on screen ruler to actual measured dimensions on the paper.
Be prepared to print lots of these test pages, tweaking measurements slightly.
Be very careful about the alignment of the paper in the printer feed tray.
